# Able to access the server with SSH, but not with SFTP

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

I have access to the server via SSH (using Putty Client), but I am not able to connect via SFTP, using same port (using FileZilla, or other clients).

Server requires public key authorization, and keys are configured properly in all clients.

What might be solution for this?

Edit: The solution in this case was using SCP protocol.

Comment: It is possible that SFTP is disabled on the server but this is unusual (at least as a default install).

Do you have any logging output from your SSH and SFTP connection attempt?  What is the actual failure message?

Comment: This is the Filezilla only error log:

Error: Connection closed by server with exitcode 127

Error: Could not connect to server

Comment: Are you able to log into the server and follow the log output from sshd?

Comment: This is only output from /var/log/auth.log

Mar 11 11:05:01 localhost CRON[4163]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 11 11:05:01 localhost CRON[4165]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user www-data by (uid=0)
Mar 11 11:05:01 localhost CRON[4164]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user www-data by (uid=0)
Mar 11 11:05:01 localhost CRON[4163]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root

Comment: Hmm none of that's SSH. Try one of the other log files?
Also your sshd_config (usually in /etc/ssh/) should have a line like this: "Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server"

Comment: Thank you very much @GerdBusker, I solved the issue, the Filezilla doesn't support SCP protocol, and once I tried the same config via SCP it worked.